# How does the definition of reishit differ from bereishit?

Tags: words, parashat-bereishit

If I am not mistaken, the Hebrew word for "in the beginning" in Bereishit 1:1, could have been *reishit*.  However, the word used was *bereshit*.  It is my understanding that the  use of bereshit (*reishit* with a *bet* at its beginning) is significant in that, by the inclusion of the second letter in the Aleph Bet, may indicate a second beginning, or a recreation.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have done some writing on this word because of the confusing nature of the word "bereishit." It is both a root plus prefix and suffix (reish plus b- and -it) and a complete word on its own marking a specific moment. I can pass info along if you'd like.

Comment: Do you have a source or reason to back up your under standing?

Answer (score 3):

The *b-* means "in". Just as in English, where you can't say "the beginning, such-and-such happened" but rather say "in the beginning, such-and-such happened", in Hebrew you need to say *b'reshis* not *reshis*. That's why the *b-* is there.

Answer (score 3):

At least on a basic level, there is no reason why the addition of a *bet* would signify a second beginning. Furthermore, *reishit* in Biblical Hebrew cannot mean "in the beginning"; it is an adjective meaning "the first of", and it must be attached to a noun (e.g. "*reishit bikkurei admat'cha*" - "the first of the fruits of your land").

Comment: _Midrash Raba_ addresses this point (not directly - but according to commetaries this is the hidden question)

Comment: @JNF - By all means, feel free to elaborate and produce your source, maybe even in a new answer.